# React Js - Issue about rendering Lightbox component in dynamic way

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I have this dependency installed:

http://jfcaiceo.github.io/react-lightbox-component/

I'm trying to render it in a dynamic way but I can't succeed. Maybe I'm doing some misstep.

Here is My Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'    
import Lightbox from 'react-lightbox-component';

const URL = 'http://localhost:3001/houses';

class Casas extends Component {    
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      index: 0,     
      currentHouse: [],     
      photos: [] 
    };       
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(URL)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({           
          currentHouse: res.data
        })
      })
  }

  render() {
    const { currentHouse, index } = this.state;    

    const images = currentHouse.length && currentHouse[index] && currentHouse[index].photos;

    const renderImages = images && images.map((photo, index) => {   
      return (
          {
            src: `../images/${photo}.jpg`
          }
        )
    })

        <div>
          <div className="gallery">
           <Lightbox images={renderImages} />             
        </div>    
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default Casas
```

Here is the db.json I'm using to be fetched by Axios. The 'photos' array is might be rendered.

```
{
  "houses": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "some text",
      "text": "some text",
      "photos": [
        "img_1",
        "img_2",
        "img_3"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "some text",
      "text": "some text",
      "photos": [
        "img_1",
        "img_2",
        "img_3"
      ]
    }
]
```

Does anybody know how to solve it?

Comment: do u want to load all house photos array or photos based on separate houses object?

Comment: I don't know what is the better solution to your question. You can do the way you think is better.

Comment: @claudiobitar are you looking for a solution like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-v5dzd6 ?

Comment: Yes. Exactly like this

Comment: publish your code of your answer here in SO. I will mark as right too. If you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third party plug-in `react-lightbox-component` expecting the below format always

```
 var images = {
  [
    {
      src: 'some image url',
      title: 'image title',
      description: 'image description'
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

So in your code in `render()`

1. `currentHouse.length` is 0, so images will be 0 in this line `var images = houses.length && houses[index] && houses[index].photos;` then renderImages also 0.
2. `react-lightbox-component` receives 0, hence it won't render

then your app throws an error and stops.

To make this work:

1. You need to check the length of `currentHouse.length` then render the `react-lightbox-component`

like below :

```
 {
     this.state.currentHouse.length > 0  
        ? <Lightbox images={renderImages }/>   
        : null
   }
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-v5dzd6)

Answer (score 1):

There are some syntax errors in your code. You have to fetch the images from currentHouse.houses and seems you are fetching it from currentHouse directly. Below code is working fine. Please have a look:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
import Lightbox from 'react-lightbox-component';

class Casa extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        index: 0,
        currentHouse: [],
        photos: []
    };
}

componentDidMount() {

    axios.get('books.json')
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                currentHouse: res.data
            })
        })
}

render() {
    const {
        currentHouse,
        index
    } = this.state;

    const images = currentHouse.houses && currentHouse.houses.length && currentHouse.houses[index] && currentHouse.houses[index].photos;

    const renderImages = images && images.map((photo, index) => {
        return ({
            src: `../images/${photo}.jpg`
        })
    });
    return (
        <div>
            <div className = "gallery" > {images && <Lightbox images = { 
               renderImages}/> }</div>     
        </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Casa;
```